# REST URI convention - Involves different resources

Tags: rest, api-design, uri

I am designing a REST API but came across some difficulties while naming it. I have an API like this:

```
GET   .../users/{userId}/categories/count
GET   .../users/{userId}/categories/{categoryId}/count
GET   .../users/{userId}/categories/{categoryId}/tickets
```

It seems like the API is about users' categories, but actually the usages are:

`Get the number of tickets for each available ticket categories for specified user`

`Get the number of tickets for the specified ticket category for specified user`

`Get all the tickets under the specified ticket category for specified user`

For the first 2 APIs, I might change this to:

```
.../users/{userId}/tickets/categories/count

.../users/{userId}/tickets/categories/{categoryId}/count
```

But for the last one, I am not sure how to design the API path. Is it weird if I change it to:

```
.../users/{userId}/tickets/categories/{categoryId}/tickets
```

Answer (score 6):

From your description category seems more like an attribute of a ticket than a discrete entity. Therefore I would use a query parameter to filter the tickets by category.

```
.../users/{userId}/tickets                             #1
.../users/{userId}/tickets?category=categoryId         #2
.../users/{userId}/tickets/count                       #3
.../users/{userId}/tickets/count?category=categoryId   #4
```

1. Gets all user's tickets in all categories
2. Gets all user's tickets in the given category
3. Gets the count of user's tickets in all categories
4. Gets the count of user's tickets in the given category